Amazon SP API patch op operation FulfillmentAvailability
How can I send the path_body to update quantities via the SP API of Amazon Seller Central in Python?
For example, I have this code:
request_params = {
    "MarketplaceIds": marketplace_id,  # required parameter
    "CreatedAfter": (
        datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=60)
    ).isoformat(),  # orders created since 30 days ago, the date needs to be in the ISO format
}

#UPDATE QTA
def update_inventory():
    url = "https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/XXXXXXXX/1AAA-3333-VVVV"
    
    headers = {
        "x-amz-access-token": access_token,  
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-amz-date": datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"),
        "Host": "sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com",
        "x-amz-marketplace-id": marketplace_id,  # My marketplace ID
    }

    patch_body = {
        "marketplaceIds": "APJ6JRA9NG5V4",
        "patches": [
            {
                "op": "replace",
                "path": "/attributes/fulfillment_availability",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "fulfillment_channel_code": "DEFAULT",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    response = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(patch_body))

    return response.json()


In the PATCH operation, what am I doing wrong?
I'm getting an InvalidInput error, and I'm unsure how to create calls to update data, while I have no issues with regular GET requests.

PATCH request, as per Amazon SP-API official documentation, there are few issues in your request:

you are missing the productType element in the body root. You can set it to PRODUCT. Every product in the Amazon's catalog inherits from this base product type, which contains informations on quantity and price (and other attributes). You can download the corresponding schema, invoking the getDefinitionsProductType (see here).
The marketplaceIds element, is wrongly placed, because it has to be passed as a GET parameter (i.e. in querystring)

Summing up, your request must be performed like this:
def update_inventory():
    url = "https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/XXXXXXXX/1AAA-3333-VVVV?marketplaceIds=APJ6JRA9NG5V4"
    
    headers = {
        "x-amz-access-token": access_token,  
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-amz-date": datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"),
        "Host": "sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com",
        "x-amz-marketplace-id": marketplace_id,  # My marketplace ID
    }

    patch_body = {
        "productType": "PRODUCT",
        "patches": [
            {
                "op": "replace",
                "path": "/attributes/fulfillment_availability",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "fulfillment_channel_code": "DEFAULT",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    response = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(patch_body))

    return response.json()

